# Changing CCSprite position leads to disappearing from screen

Tags: c#, cocos2d-x, cocossharp

Faced strange behaviour of `CCSprite` positioning on a screen. 
Scenario is simple: change sprite position on touch (dragging item on a screen).

```
private void HandleInput(List<CCTouch> arg1, CCEvent arg2)
{
    base.Position = arg1.Last().LocationOnScreen;
}
```

After setting `base.Position` to `LocationOnScreen` it simply disappears.

---

*NOTE:* `cocossharp` is a c# port of famous framework and is quite similar in its structure and implementation to `cocos2d-x` hence adding this tag.

 Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging `arg1.Last().LocationOnScreen`? Where is your  `base` added?

Comment: Location seems to be reasonable (it points to coordinates within visible screen).

Answer (score 2):

In cocos2d-x nodes are positioned relative to their parents content area.

Typically, to position a sprite in cocos2d-x using a touch derived (world space) co-ordinate you would use the convertToNodeSpace method on the parent.

In c++ because cocos2d-x:

```
void setSpritePositionWhenTouched(Node* sprite, const Vec2& touchPos)
{
  auto parent = sprite->getParent();
  auto pos = parent->convertToNodeSpace(touchPos);
  sprite->setPosition(pos);
}
```